# Allow user to install 32bit version on 64bit windows

Tags: windows, 32bit-64bit, inno-setup

I have a simple inno-setup script that allows my setup to install either the 32bit or 64bit version of my program based on the Is64BitInstallMode value.  This works great, but I'd like to give users the option to install the 32bit version even if they are on 64bit Windows.  I'd like the choice to be made before choosing the application install path so that it can default to either the 32bit or 64bit program files folder based on their choice.  I'd also like to avoid the question entirely if they are on 32bit windows.  I've been playing with the various features, but haven't figured a way to do it yet.  If I can't do it easily I'll just do two separate installs (and I'm trying to decide what makes the most sense!)  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually done the following yet, but this is what I'd try:

1. You need a new installer page that allows the user to choose whether the 32bit or 64bit version should be installed (this page should only be made visible on a 64bit Windows)
2. You need a variable that holds an indicator for the "bittyness" the user has selected. It should be initialized to 32bit on 32bit systems and to 64bit on 64bit systems depending on `Is64BitInstallMode`.
3. After the page in 1. has been finished, you should update the variable created in 2. with the value that reflects the user's choice.
4. Add the files for both 32bit and 64bit version to the installer
5. Add a new function that returns `true` if the 64bit version should be installed (e.g. `Install64BitVersion`)
6. Add a new function that returns `true` if the 32bit version should be installed (e.g. `Install32BitVersion`)
7. Change the `File` entries in the `Files` section to be installed conditionally:

This is an example for the `Files` section:

```
[Files]
Source: 32bitexe.exe; DestDir: {...}; Check: Install32BitVersion
Source: 64bitexe.exe; DestDir: {...}; Check: Install64BitVersion
```

Comment: Thanks, I see another answer from you regarding making custom pages, so I'll experiment with the custom page idea.  Any thoughts on changing the default destination directory before showing that page?

Comment: Actually, you should consider changing it *after* showing the page. I didn't mention it as I'm not sure whether it is a problem when a 32bit application is installed under the 64bit program files folder.

Comment: I found another question that answered how to do it by modifying the edit field in code.  I just want to change the initial default, I don't want to override the users choice since they might choose not to install in program files (either version) at all.

Comment: I know - I meant: Let the user choose whether to install the 32bit or 64bit version (via new page). Then modify the suggested installation path before letting the user select the path. I didn't mean to change the user's selection, but in your question you suggested showing the "32/64bit page" before letting the user select the installation location, so that's what I was referring to.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten.  Sorry, I should have been more clear than saying "that page".  After playing with this for a bit, I'm really thinking of just going with two separate installers instead of a combined one.